# TCP response breaks after 1460bytes

Tags: server, response, break, tcpclient, mss

Response from one linux server to another linux server breaks after 1460 bytes , checked on server (MTU is default 1500).
but why it is happening to few requests only because all responses are more than 1460 bytes.

Comment: Without seeing any code it's difficult to be sure but your use of the words "request" and "response" are suggestive. TCP is an *endless stream of bytes* (in both directions). There aren't distinct requests nor responses unless *you* perform some form of message framing on top of the endless streams

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for clarity. It is buffer outputstream that i am sending using python socket programming to client. It is just a basic python socket program. for reference : In server response function :  s = socket.socket()     s.connect((host,port))   s.sendall(c)